# Dynamic scaling of iFrame content to fit div width

Tags: html, css, iframe, webkit

The site I am working on has a bit of content to be called inside an iFrame. The content within the iframe has a known width, and an indeterminate height. While the page looks just fine on my 1080 monitor, the page is designed to scale between desktop, laptop, and portrait tablets. Because the contents of the iFrame are predetermined and are laid out in a way that cannot change or resize, I am trying to scale the contents of the frame to fit the width of the div it is wrapped in.

I can, of course, set `-webkit-transform: scale` to scale the frame contents, but that doesn't resize correctly across screen resolutions. I suspect that there might be some javascript I could use to get the width of "column3" and scale the iFrame to match, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to what that code would look like. All solutions I have seen to this point seem to function around resizing the frame itself, but do not account for scaling the content of that frame.

Any thoughts?

Here is my code: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Nightglow2006/kwgvdh81/)

```css
#wrap { 
    width: 1200px;
    height: 390px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#frame {
    width: 900px;
    height: 520px;
    border: 0;
}
#frame {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.70);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#column1 {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
    height:20px;
}
#column2 {
    background-color: LightSteelBlue;
    height: 20px;
}
#column3 {
    background-color: PaleGreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="column1" class="col-xs-2">
    </div>
    <div id="column2" class="col-xs-4">
    </div>
    <div id="column3" class="col-xs-6">
        <div id="wrap">
            <iframe id="frame" src="https://xkcd.com/" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the iframe's height by the width to get a percentage of padding to apply to the iframe's parent that will force the parent element's aspect ratio, then absolutely position the iframe with 100% height/width for the iframe to scale responsively.

```css
#wrap { padding-top: 57.7%; height: 0; position: relative; }
#frame { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; }

#column1 {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
    height:20px;
}
#column2 {
    background-color: LightSteelBlue;
    height: 20px;
}
#column3 {
    background-color: PaleGreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
    <div id="column1" class="col-xs-2">

    </div>

    <div id="column2" class="col-xs-4">

    </div>

    <div id="column3" class="col-xs-6">

        <div id="wrap">
            <iframe id="frame" src="https://xkcd.com/" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This resizes the frame, but does not scale the content of that frame. Ideally, the content of frame itself (xkcd.com, in this case), should be "zoomed out" such that the entire content of the page fits within the confines of the "column3" div. 

Otherwise, this is a nice, elegant way to adjust the width and height of the frame itself, even if it doesn't do anything about the content. Nice!

Comment: I'm working an alternative method to solving my problem. If anyone runs across this in the future, dynamically scaling the contents of an iframe to fit the width and height constraints of a div will require some javascript to get the proper aspect ratio of the div in addition to something similar to above. If anyone wants to take a stab at this, feel free - but this is being considered closed / abandoned without answer.